# Arc Length: Surface of revolution

Tags: arc-length

The given arc is $y = 1 - \dfrac {x^2}{4}$ about the $y$-axis from 0 to 2. 
Here is the farthest part I could ever go through.

$$y’ = -\frac{x}{2}$$

$$[y’]^2 = \frac{x^2}{4}$$

So $$\int_0^2x\cdot\sqrt{1+\frac{x^2}{4}}\,dx$$ What should I do next? Thanks for those who will help. I have a quiz later and I can’t solve similar problems like this.

Comment: Check your derivative...

Comment: Yes. Go again and look. I’ve done it.

Comment: Do you mean to ask for the arc length, or the surface area of the solid formed? Could you explain what formula you are using?

Comment: Is there a factor of $2\pi$ missing?

Comment: It's possible that no one has answered your question because it is a straightforward $u$-substitution problem which you should be able to do on your own.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are trying to find the surface area for this surface of revolution which is revolved around the $y$-axis, the formula to compute it is 
$$A = \int_a^b 2 \pi x \sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}dx$$
Note in your work, you are missing the $2\pi$. To compute your integral, you need a $u$-substitution. Try $u= 1+\frac{x^2}{4}$. Then $du = \frac{x}{2}dx \Rightarrow dx=\frac{2du}{x}$. Your bounds will also change, since you are now doing an integral with respect to $u$ instead of $x$. 
$$\int_0^2 \to \int_1^2$$
These new bounds come from plugging in $0$ and $2$ into your $u=1+\frac{x^2}{4}$ equation. Your new integral looks like: 
$$A = \int_1^2 2\pi x \sqrt{u}\frac{2du}{x} = 4 \pi \int_1^2 \sqrt{u}du$$

And from here, it is an integral that you can compute. Hope this helps!